# Wildcard in Hadoop's FileSystem listing API calls

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, wildcard

***`tl;dr:`*** To be able to use wildcards (globs) in the listed paths, one simply has to use [`globStatus(...)`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter)) instead of [`listStatus(...)`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter)).

---

## Context

Files on my HDFS cluster are organized in partitions, with the date being the *"root"* partition. A simplified example of the files structure would look like this:

```
/schemas_folder
├── date=20140101
│   ├── A-schema.avsc
│   ├── B-schema.avsc
├── date=20140102
│   ├── A-schema.avsc
│   ├── B-schema.avsc
│   ├── C-schema.avsc
└── date=20140103
    ├── B-schema.avsc
    └── C-schema.avsc
```

In my case, the directory stores [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/) schemas for different types of data *(A, B and C in this example)* at different dates. The schema might start existing, evolve and stop existing... as time passes.

---

## Goal

I need to be able to get all the schemas that exist for a given type, as quickly as possible. In the example where I would like to get all the schemas that exist for type A, I would like to do the following:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /schemas_folder/date=*/A-schema.avsc
```

That would give me

```
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 user group 1234 2014-01-01 12:34 /schemas_folder/date=20140101/A-schema.avsc
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 user group 2345 2014-01-02 23:45 /schemas_folder/date=20140102/A-schema.avsc
```

---

## Problem

I don't want to be using the shell command, and cannot seem to find the equivalent to that command above in the Java APIs. When I try to implement the looping myself, I get terrible performance. I want *at least* the performance of the command line (around **3 seconds** in my case)...

---

## What I found so far

One can notice that it prints twice `Found 1 items`, once before each result. It does not print `Found 2 items` once at the beginning. That probably hints that wildcards are not implemented on the `FileSystem` side but somehow handled by the client. I can't seem to find the right source code to look at to see how that was implemented.

Below are my first shots, probably a bit too naïve...

### Using listFiles(...)

#### Code:

```
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> files = filesystem.listFiles(new Path("/schemas_folder"), true);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*/date=[0-9]{8}/A-schema\\.avsc$");
while (files.hasNext()) {
    Path path = files.next().getPath();
    if (pattern.matcher(path.toString()).matches())
    {
        System.out.println(path);
    }
}
```

#### Result:

This prints exactly what I would expect, but since it first lists everything recursively and then filters, the performance is really poor. With my current dataset, it takes almost **25 seconds**...

### Using listStatus(...)

#### Code:

```
FileStatus[] statuses = filesystem.listStatus(new Path("/schemas_folder"), new PathFilter()
{
    private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^date=[0-9]{8}$");

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path path)
    {
        return pattern.matcher(path.getName()).matches();
    }
});
Path[] paths = new Path[statuses.length];
for (int i = 0; i < statuses.length; i++) { paths[i] = statuses[i].getPath(); }
statuses = filesystem.listStatus(paths, new PathFilter()
{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path path)
    {
        return "A-schema.avsc".equals(path.getName());
    }
});
for (FileStatus status : statuses)
{
    System.out.println(status.getPath());
}
```

#### Result:

Thanks to the `PathFilter`s and the use of arrays, it seems to perform faster (around **12 seconds**). The code is more complex, though, and more difficult to adapt to different situations. Most importantly, the performance is still 3 to 4 times slower than the command-line version!

---

## Question

**What am I missing here? What is the fastest way to get the results I want?**

---

## Updates

### 2014.07.09 - 13:38

The proposed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24651078/1994863) of [Mukesh S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1970125/mukesh-s) is apparently the best possible API approach.

In the example I gave above, the code end-up looking like this:

```
FileStatus[] statuses = filesystem.globStatus(new Path("/schemas_folder/date=*/A-schema.avsc"));
for (FileStatus status : statuses)
{
    System.out.println(status.getPath());
}
```

This is the best looking and best performing code I could come up with so far, but is still not performing as well as the shell version.

Comment: Did you end up finding a more efficient way to run this? `globStatus` takes an extraordinary amount of time compared to shell for me as well.. :/

Comment: @Idos I did not. :(

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Instead of listStatus you can try hadoops globStatus. Hadoop provides two FileSystem method for processing globs:

```
public FileStatus[] globStatus(Path pathPattern) throws IOException
public FileStatus[] globStatus(Path pathPattern, PathFilter filter) throws IOException
```

An optional PathFilter can be specified to restrict the matches further.

For more description you can check Hadoop:Definitive Guide [here](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-3/the-java-interface)

Hope it helps..!!!

Comment: This sounds perfect, I will accept as soon as I've tested if it works!

Comment: just what is needed. straightforward. kudos