# Spark - Get from a directory with nested folders all filenames of a particular data type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a directory with some subfolders which content different parquet files. Something like this:

```
2017-09-05
    10-00
        part00000.parquet
        part00001.parquet
    11-00
        part00000.parquet
        part00001.parquet
    12-00
        part00000.parquet
        part00001.parquet
```

What I want is by passing the path to the directory 05-09 to get a list of names of all parquet files.

I was able to achieve it, but in a very inefficient way:

```
 val allParquetFiles = sc.wholeTextFiles("C:/MyDocs/2017-09-05/*/*.parquet")
 allParquetFiles.keys.foreach((k) => println("The path to the file is: "+k))
```

So each key is the name I am looking for, but this process requires me to load all files as well, which then I can't use, since I get them in binary (and I don't know how to convert them into a dataframe).

Once I have the keys (so the list of filePaths) I am planning to invoke:

```
val myParquetDF = sqlContext.read.parquet(filePath);
```

As you may have already understood I am quite new in Spark. So please if there is a faster or easier approach to read a list of parquet files located in different folders, please let me know.

**My Partial Solution**: I wasn't able to get all paths for all filenames in a folder, but I was able to get the content of all files of that type into the same dataframe. Which was my ultimate goal. In case someone may need it in the future, I used the following line:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("C:/MyDocs/2017-05-09/*/*.parquet")
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: You can create a map of `filename -> DataFrame` using `sc.wholeTextFiles("path/*/*/").map(x => x._1 -> sqlContext.read.parquet(x._2) )` but it looks extremely weird , specially when there are hunderds of files.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the hdfs api like this

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.conf._ 
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val files = ( fs.listStatus(new Path("C:/MyDocs/2017-09-05/*/*.parquet")) ).map(_.getPath.toString)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, do you know the import for Path? I am looking for it, but if you already know it, please add it as well

Comment: Path is in org.apache.hadoop.fs

Comment: Ok but with this solution the wildcard of the subfolders doesnt work. I am getting: FileNotFoundException for the path

Comment: In fact, I have already use this solution but with any wildcard in the Path. Here is a more complex answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/24647992/6138873

Comment: But I need the wildcard, because I dont know how many subfolders may be and their names.

Answer (score 2):

First, it is better to avoid using `wholeTextFiles`. This method reads the whole file at once. Try to use `textFile` method. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940704/memory-usage-of-sc-textfile-vs-sc-wholetextfiles-flatmapvalues)

Second, if you need to get all files recursively in one directory, you can achieve it by `textFile` method:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", "true")
```

This configuration will enable recursive search (works for spark jobs as for mapreduce jobs). And then just invoke `sc.textFile(path)`.

Comment: But with that am I getting the file or the file name?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre you get the RDD with content of all files