# How to use wildcard in hdfs file path while list out files in nested folder

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using below code to list out files in nested folder
val hdfspath="/data/retail/apps/*/landing"

import org.apache.hadoop.fs. (FileSystem, Path) val fs= org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get (spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration) fs.listStatus (new Path (s"S(hdfspath)")).filter(.isDirectory).map(_.getPath).foreach (printin)

If I  use path as below
hdfspath="/data/retail/apps"
getting results but if I use val hdfspath="/data/retail/apps/*/landing" then I'm getting error it's showing path not exist error.plese help me out.

[image]
Error Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647992/wildcard-in-hadoops-filesystem-listing-api-calls), you need to use globStauts instead of listStatus:

```
fs.globStatus(new Path (s"S(hdfspath)")).filter(.isDirectory).map(_.getPath).foreach (println)
```

Comment: Above solutions is working for me. Now I have to take count of no of files in list how I can get it.please help me.